# Get all the line numbers in a C++ program where function calls are invoked

Tags: c++, gdb

For example, I have a C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>

int main() {

    int a =0;
    //A vector of size 10 with all values as 1
    std::vector<std::size_t> v(10, 1);
    assert(v.size() == 10);
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to find the line number where a function call is invoked:

So, I would line numbers where vector v is constructed and when size() function of vector is invoked.

Utility in any programming language is accepted, but preference would be given to a gdb solution to look for function invocations.

Comment: Most IDE's have a "Find All References" or similar functionality.

Comment: Doxygen can make a callee and caller graph.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I would prefer an automated solution at runtime.

Comment: The compiler is free to rearrange your code such that there is no longer any relationship between line numbers and function calls. It looks like an XY problem anyway, why do you need this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would line numbers where vector v is constructed and when size() function of vector is invoked.

There is no easy way to do so in GDB, but you could use `objdump -d` to get the addresses of `CALL` instructions. Example: using your program, adding missing `#include <assert.h>` and building it with:

```
$ gcc -g t.cc -fno-pie -no-pie

$ objdump -dC a.out | grep 'call.*>::vector'
  4011da:   e8 f9 00 00 00          callq  4012d8 <std::vector<unsigned long, std::allocator<unsigned long> >::vector(unsigned long, unsigned long const&, std::allocator<unsigned long> const&)>

$ objdump -dC a.out | grep 'call.*>::size'
  4011f2:   e8 8f 01 00 00          callq  401386 <std::vector<unsigned long, std::allocator<unsigned long> >::size() const>
```

Now that you know the addresses of `CALL` instructions, you can translate them into function/file/line using `addr2line`:

```
$ addr2line -fe a.out 4011da 4011f2
main
/tmp/t.cc:9
main
/tmp/t.cc:10 (discriminator 1)
```

Comment: Just a follow up question, why is -fno-pie -no-pie required here.

Comment: @goodfellas95 The `-fno-pie` is not required, but makes understanding the example easier (my GCC defaults to producing PIE binaries).